# I've created a stored procedure (CURD application) using entity framework in asp.net mvc 4, but I am getting error when am trying to insert data

Tags: sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, crud

I've created a stored procedure (CURD application) using entity framework in asp.net mvc 4, but I am getting error when am trying to insert data

Error: 
Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.

db.SaveChanges();

and this the code :

```
 using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using OlFood.Models;

    namespace OlFood.Controllers
    {
        public class AdminDashBoardController : Controller
        {
            private MyDataBaseEntities1 db = new MyDataBaseEntities1();

            //
            // GET: /AdminDashBoard/

            public ActionResult Index()
            {
                return View(db.Products.ToList());
            }

            //
            // GET: /AdminDashBoard/Details/5

            public ActionResult Details(string id = null)
            {
                Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
                if (product == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(product);
            }

            //
            // GET: /AdminDashBoard/Create

            public ActionResult Create()
            {
                return View();
            }

            //
            // POST: /AdminDashBoard/Create

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Create(Product product)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Products.Add(product);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }

                return View(product);
            }

            //
            // GET: /AdminDashBoard/Edit/5

            public ActionResult Edit(string id = null)
            {
                Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
                if (product == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(product);
            }

            //
            // POST: /AdminDashBoard/Edit/5

            [HttpPost]
            public ActionResult Edit(Product product)
            {
                if (ModelState.IsValid)
                {
                    db.Entry(product).State = EntityState.Modified;
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    return RedirectToAction("Index");
                }
                return View(product);
            }

            //
            // GET: /AdminDashBoard/Delete/5

            public ActionResult Delete(string id = null)
            {
                Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
                if (product == null)
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
                return View(product);
            }

            //
            // POST: /AdminDashBoard/Delete/5

            [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
            public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(string id)
            {
                Product product = db.Products.Find(id);
                db.Products.Remove(product);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
                base.Dispose(disposing);
            }
        }
    }
```

am not getting why it showing error...

Comment: Line 63:                     db.SaveChanges();

Comment: Please post the detailed error or stack. We wont be able to help you much based on the just the above info.

Comment: On a separate note, put a break point on the Create method and look for the attributes of the new Product you are trying to insert and see if all the attributes have the desired values in the correct format

Comment: Check you have setup your database correctly in SQL Management studio, i.e permissions to create